# C++: BOOST-ASIO read_handler() does not work as expected?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, polling

On line 67 I have the code

```
void session::read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
      std::cout<<bytes_transferred<<std::endl;
}
```

Which is supposed to be polled whenever the server receives a packet in the session class but for some reason the function is never called. The `io_service.run();` is called in the `int main()` for the [`read_handler()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html). The code is basically the example on the Boost site for the async server with the function added by me. Heres the code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session
{
public:
  session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start()
  {
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);


private:
  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};
void session::read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
      std::cout<<bytes_transferred<<std::endl;
}

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    start_accept();
  }


private:
  void start_accept()
  {
    session* new_session = new session(io_service_);
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(session* new_session,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_session->start();
    }
    else
    {
      delete new_session;
    }

    start_accept();
  }

  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    server s(io_service, 4000);

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

session::read_handler(...) was not set as handler.

handle_accept() is called because it is set as handler:

```
acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

handle_read(...) is called bacause it is set as handler:

```
socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Same for handle_write(...) - set by handle_read function.

But read_handler is not set. Use handle_read instead. Or call read_handler from handle_read.

```
  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      std::cout<<bytes_transferred<<std::endl; // try this.
      read_handler(error, bytes_transferred);  // OR this.

      boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The function gets never called because you neither call it nor pass it as a handler to one of the async functions.

you can see the handlers as states of a state machine, and the async_* calls as transitions between these states. your states are the following (starting point is `start_accept`, called from `server::server`:

```
<<start>>                   --async_accept-----> <server::handle_accept> //via server::server > server::start_accept
<server::handle_accept>     --async_read_some--> <session::handle_read>  //via session::start
<session::handle_read>      --async_write------> <session::handle_write>
<session::handle_write>     --async_read_some--> <session::handle_read>
```

The paths are only for the cases without error. Error cases are trivial, they just end the program or, in case of `handle_accept` just retry the transition.

You can see the possibly endless cycle between `handle_read` and `handle_write`, but `read_handler` is not part of the game.